# implement in a windows service of Listening for WMI Events in ASP.NET Health Monitoring

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, wmi

I found a nice code to monitor the health of asp.net application.

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178713(v=vs.100).aspx)

But i have some difficulties to implement in a windows service.

I executed  code in

> OnStart(string[] args)  but couldn't able to run the code..

Please guide me.